# Use Firebase Realtime database location wise

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created two Firebase realtime database in same project, to balance load

1) India_DB for India Location (https://India1232.firebaseio.com/)

2) UK_DB for UK Location (https://UKasdw3.firebaseio.com/_

I want to show data according to country wise.

Suppose, if country is India then I want to fetch data from India_DB only 
If country is UK then only from UK_DB.

How can I separate them? I am using below code to get DatabaseReference.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
```

Is it possible for Country wise automatically in firebase?

If not then If I use third party API to get country code then how can I fetch data from separate database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances), you should pass the URL of your secondary database instance to the [`getInstance()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#public-static-firebasedatabase-getinstance-string-url) method, as follows:

```
DatabaseReference secondary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://UKasdw3.firebaseio.com")
        .getReference();
```

---

I don't think you could automatically declare a specific database instance based on the Country (the instance identifier, i.e. the URL, is not linked to a location or Country). You will need to use a "third party API to get country code" as mentioned in your question, in order to get the exact URL to use (or no URL at all, in the case you target the app's default database instance).